# Using R Data.Table to find the average per day

Tags: r, data.table

my `df` looks like this:

```
total_sales    profit    day
1200            300      Sun
800             100      Mon
400             105      Fri
1900            600      Wed
900             300      Tue
1100            450      Thu
2300            200      Thu
550             175      Sat

.......
```

I want to find the average `profts` per `day`

What did I do?

- I have done the following using Data Table:

  ```
  we know that data table is:
  DT[select row, what to do , group by]

  DT[df$profit, mean, df$day]
  ```

However, it does not work. Please advice, I need to do using `Data.Table`

Comment: df[, mean(profit), day]

Comment: Are you saying that the values below are not the averages you expect? If so, then please provide what you think (at least one of) the average values *should be*.

Comment: Your `DT[df$profit,mean,df$day]` is nothing like `data.table`'s normal (NSE) nomenclature. First, using `DT[i,j,by]` nomenclature, an `i=` of `df$profit` is effectively filtering on truthy-like `profit`, which turns into any non-zero profit ... not what you mean. Your `j=mean` is returning a function, not a summary of values. Your `df$day` should be `by=day`, not `df$` ... though it works here, it's generally bad practice to reference `DT$` inside the brackets unless you must use it (for various reasons ... extraneous, possibly "wrong" here).

Comment: The `j=` argument is list-like values/function-calls/similar, not a `FUN=` that you see in other functions (e.g., `lapply`, `tapply`, `by`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
DT[, .(mu = mean(profit)), by = .(day)]
#    day  mu
# 1: Sun 300
# 2: Mon 100
# 3: Fri 105
# 4: Wed 600
# 5: Tue 300
# 6: Thu 325
# 7: Sat 175
```

---

Data:

```r
DT <- fread(text = "
total_sales    profit    day
1200            300      Sun
800             100      Mon
400             105      Fri
1900            600      Wed
900             300      Tue
1100            450      Thu
2300            200      Thu
550             175      Sat")
```

---

This is a dupe, but I'll step through why your `DT[df$profit,mean,df$day]` is a little flawed.

- `data.table` (and `dplyr`) generally (but not necessarily *always*) use non-standard evaluation for variable reference, so `day` not `"day"`, etc;
- you use both `DT` and `df`, I'm not certain if you have two variables and are mistakenly using one with the other; I'll use just `DT` here;
- there are times when you may want to reference `DT$` inside the brackets, but these are certainly the exception ... just go with variable names (as symbols);
- `i=` is looking for something truthy-like, as in a logical vector (whether to select each row) or an integer vector (which rows to select), and since your `profit` is an integer column, it will be looking for row 300, row 100, row 105, etc ... which obviously don't exist
- `j=` should be an assignment-like operation, so something like `newval := somefunc(...)` or a summary operation, like `.(newval = somefunc(...))`; *not* a `FUN=`, as in `tapply`, `lapply`, `Map`, `by`, etc
- your `by=` call is generally fine unlabeled, once you remove the `df$`, then `day` by itself is fine. I personally tend to be explicit with `by=` (so `by=day` here), as much to be declarative and easier to understand my intention as anything else (other named arguments here might include `.SDcols=` and `on=`, for various purposes).

Comment: My edit doesn't change the results but explains a little more. Hope it is informative/helpful.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much!

Comment: quick question: How do I add `total sales` per `day` on the same `DT` with `average` proft?

Comment: `DT[, .(mu = mean(profit), total = sum(total_sales)), by = day]`?

Comment: it's a `data.table` abbreviation for `list`. It works the same as `DT[, list(mu = mean(profit), ...), by=day]`